# Removing the .py file of a Django view does not actually remove the view

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a project in Django.
I'm trying to change some logic in `/pages/views.py`. But my changes are not applied. Then to test I removed `/pages/views.py` but the pages still work. When I try to delete the `/pages/templates/page.html`, I get the error, which is as it should be.
I don't understand why removing the script does not cause the error and how the site still works. The trace indicates that the script is invoked. The path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that you did not remove `pages/views.pyc` If that file is still present, then Python will load it. Whenever you remove a `.py` file make sure to remove the `.pyc` too. The `.pyc` is the "compiled" version of your `.py` file.

Comment: Thanks.
I also thought about that. deleting the wrong file. But, according to the trace the path i scorrect . I thought it might be caching or what...